# Simple Perceptron in Python with documentation

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

I've written this simple perceptron algorithm in Python

```
import numpy as nu
import random as ra

function = lambda x: 1 if x >= 0 else 0

training_set=[([1,0,0],1),
              ([1,1,1],1),
              ([1,-1,0],0),
              ([1,0,-1],0),
              ]

w = nu.random.rand(3)
eta = 0.1
print(w)

for l in range(10000):
    for _ in range(4):
        x,y = training_set[_]
        res = (function(nu.dot(w,x)) - y)
        update = eta * res
        w += nu.dot(update,x)

print(w)
```

`function` checks if `w*x>=0` or not.
I have a training set of 4 elements, the first element a `xi` vector, the second the expected result. The first element xi is the bias.
The loop continues to update the `wi` for 1000 iterations.
**The fact is that sometimes converge and sometimes not.**

Some questions:

1. The algorithm seems correct ?
2. How many training sample i have to put to assure the perfect convergence of the algorithm ?
3. Why in average the loop finishes doing 4 iterations of the training_set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you need to flip the sign of the update. You're moving away from the minimum otherwise.
2. This depends on the initial values of `w`, the learning rate, the order of training samples etc. You can't make any hard statements about the convergence.
3. Looks like you edited your code and this question became irrelevant.

Comment: Now the code is simpler, but sometimes converge and sometimes not.

Comment: It's happens a strange thing. If i check the result on python it works, but if i plot the line, the result isnt correct. Can you check ?

Comment: Oh my gosh, i was checking using the random w calculated at the beginning of the code. Could you check if the code works ?